# Question closed as too localized - it did apply to me as well and I have an answer

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924804/visual-studio-2012-pro-edition-always-hanging-immediately-after-opening-solution) got closed as too localized and as unlikely to help any future visitors. Well, I am such a future visitor, and I've found a solution to it and would like to share it. Furthermore, given the nature of the problem, it's not unlikely that more people will be affected by it as well.

Basically the problem was that at least the ISO-download of the [3 official downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) comes with an outdated version, exactly the one the OP gave in his question. It caused me the exact same exception every time I opened an sln.

The solution was not to uninstall as the comment suggests, but to download the [first update](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-additional-software), lower on the same download page. Applying that update solved the problem for me.

The OP asks about the Pro edition, Ive had the problem with the ultimate edition, so it's not only the Pro edition but presumably all editions, so it will affect even more people.

All in all, I believe the question is not too localized. If it gets re-opened, Ill be happy to answer it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I suspect I voted it as off-topic, rather than "too localized" (the way the system works out close reasons means it doesn't always get closed for the reason you vote). Simply because the question was more a product support question than a *specific programming* question, and isn't that what the vendor is there for? If it was edited to fit better with the FAQ I'd consider casting my reopen vote, but I'm just not convinced that an edit would help to be honest.

Comment: @RivieraKid: Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are explicitly [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for SO. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Questions about software tools should preferably be about how to *use* the tools, not about how to find or install them.

Comment: @BoPersson I'm not at all into how to interpret the FAQ in all its nuances, but this distinction seems quite sophisticated to me. I googled a problem I've been having, found that question as the second result, and see that it's closed, so no help. If I could answer the question, the next guy would find the answer, problem solved. Isn't that the point of SE?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen as Bo say, questions about using the tools, or accomplishing a programming task with the tool, then that's fine. Providing support for Microsoft, of all companies, is a little outside the scope of SO, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @Hackworth It is reopened now so you can add your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Part of the problem was that the question did not make all the facts (that would make it not 'too localized') apparent in the post.

There was a blob of text that wasn't well formatted, and it appears the user didn't spend a lot of time putting together the post.  Here are some things that would have helped it stay open:

- Better formatting: There was a lot of lowercase and badly punctuated (if at all) sentences
- Less time explaining he has a problem, and more time explaining the relevant facts
- Formatting the relevant facts
- Asking a question instead of an open ended 'any ideas?'.

You're right, the question isn't too localized, but without effort from the OP, how can we expect answerers to give their effort to solve the user's issue?

I'm not passing judgment on the community's call here; just sharing what I've learned from being here a few years.

I've taken the liberty of editing the post so it's easier to follow. In the future, I recommend you do the same. Once you edit it and vote to re-open it, there's a chance it will be re-opened by others (especially if you leave a comment explaining why it should be re-opened).  If, after an acceptable amount of time has passed, it's still not open, then ping us on Meta.